# How to connect a C# application to a sql database using php

Tags: c#, php, sql

I am trying to connect my C# application to sql server using php since my sever is Web Hosting.

I tried using Web Client Class

```
private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

              string Userinput = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://zrm.unaux.com/Login.php?Username=" + txtUsername.Text + "&Password=" + txtPass.Text);
            switch (Userinput.ToLower())
            {
                case "1":
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("1");
                        break;
                    }

                case "2":
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("2");
                        break;
                    }
                case "3":
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("3");
                        break;
                    }
                default :
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Not Connected");
                        break;
                    }
            }
```

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/aes.js\" ></script>
    <script>
      function toNumbers(d) {
        var e = [];
        d.replace(/(..)/g, function(d) {
          e.push(parseInt(d, 16))
        });
        return e
      }

      function toHex() {
        for (var d = [], d = 1 == arguments.length && arguments[0].constructor == Array ? arguments[0] : arguments, e = \"\",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?\"0\":\"\")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers(\"f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4\"),b=toNumbers(\"98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80\"),c=toNumbers(\"8fdda47311600c481f5f2fe34d2c79e3\");document.cookie=\"__test=\"+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+\"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/\"; location.href=\"http://zrm.unaux.com/Login.php?Username=zeph&Password=123&i=1\
    </script>
    <noscript>
      This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your 
      browser or use a browser with Javascript support
    </noscript>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Could you please try and edit your question so the code is readable? The editor has buttons at the top to do this. My first question would be: Why use PHP, why not connect directly to the SQL database? I guess because it is not allowed by your webhost?

Comment: I would say remove the `noscript` tag from the html if you're going to use WebClient and not a browser.